# How could extension cord detection be implemented in Tesla Roadster?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage, wiring

Googling finds evidence that Tesla Roadster electric car can detect cases when it is plugged in via extension cord.

Specifically [this page](http://www.teslamotorsclub.com/showwiki.php?title=Roadster) lists error codes 937 and 9 meaning "extension cord detected". And [this post](http://www.teslamotorsclub.com/showthread.php/9425-Charging-on-an-extension-cord?p=165014&viewfull=1#post165014) says that when a cable with 2.5 square millimeters cross-section in each wire is used the charging goes just fine but when a cable with 1.5 square millimeters cross-section in each wire is used the car displays "extension cord detected" message.

Now the latter post says it's because of notable voltage drop on a thinner cable. Looks reasonable but the lower voltage on the car end of the cable can be because the mains voltage gets lower than the nominal, not because of voltage drop in the cable.

How can such check be implemented so that it only detects thin wires and ignores cases when mains voltage is low?

Comment: Are you definite that the same error would not be generated due to too-low voltage at power source? Also, one simple way of detecting whether the voltage is low versus the power cord being too high-impedance, would be to ***very briefly*** open a low-impedance path (essentially a near short-circuit) and measure the current through it. For low voltage, current would still be relatively unconstrained, so a design permitting say 15 Amperes for this pulse, would see the 15 Amperes. For thinner cables or extension cords, this would not necessarily be so. Hence, detection feasible.

Comment: The car's charge controller can turn OFF the load too and monitor the open circuit voltage from the charger. With no current draw the size of wire in the extension cord would not disturb the open circuit voltage measurement. Once again providing date to make extension cord detection feasible.

Answer (score 8):

The car can draw a variable amount of current. By measuring how much the voltage changes at two different current levels, it can distinguish between low source voltage (low mains voltage) and high source impedance (small-gauge extension cord).

Comment: What if the mains voltage rises after the "low current" measurement and that compensates for the voltage drop?

Comment: That would require a very specific time and value of mains voltage change - you could probably fake it deliberately, but it's very very unlikely to happen by coincidence.

Comment: @sharptooth You do it several times, reject outliers and compute the average.

Comment: I don't really get it. Why would voltage drop be different at different currents if the resistance is the same?

Comment: Because of Ohm's Law: V = I*R. The voltage drop across the series resistance is proportional to the current through it.

Comment: Is this because I have to change the load resistance in order to change the current and so the overall resistance changes?